# LOAD DATA INFILE not working with FIELDS TERMINATED BY

Tags: php, mysql, load-data-infile, file-io

I'm using the sql below in a php script:

```
$sql1 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test1.csv' INTO TABLE number1 (order_num,pname)";
$sql2 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test1.csv' INTO TABLE number1 (order_num,pname) FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    printf("<br>Section 4: %s",$mysqli->error);
    printf("|$result|$table");
} else {
    printf("<br>Section 5: %s",$mysqli->error);
}
```

If I use `$sql1` it properly brings 3 lines into the db (doesn't break them into proper fields). No error returned. If I use `$sql2` it returns message:

`"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'.."`

I've tried different order, using ENCLOSED BY with it / instead of it..  Everything I can think of. Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)...  The field declaration must come after the fields terminated by declaration:

```
$sql2 = "LOAD DATA LOCAL 
            INFILE 'test1.csv' 
            INTO TABLE number1 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'
            (order_num,pname)";
```

Comment: Yes, been camped on that page all night. Could have sworn I tried that variation..  Works, thanks for quick reply.

Comment: I've been trying to debug my statement for an hour and was reading the documentation over, and over. I can't believe I missed that, I had exact same problem. Just thought I would post a comment saying thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yep the (order_num,pname) is invalid there's a different syntax for mapping fields to column names.

Comment: It's valid (that's what the docs show at least, and that's not where the error is coming from)...

Comment: As you said it goes at the end - not where he had it so syntax error.